# flutter pub get error. SDK version error. how do i solve it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So this is my error when i run `Flutter pub get` .

```
Because Quiz requires SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because Quiz requires SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

And this is my code from the pubspec.yaml file...

```
name: 'Quiz'
description: The Quiz from Gabriël!

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: false
  image_path: "./playstore.png"
```

Comment: what do you get from `flutter --version`